# Can't access RabbitMQ web management interface from external ips

Tags: rabbitmq

After a fresh install of RabbitMQ server on CentOs 7.7

I can reach the :15672 port from localhost

```
curl -i http://localhost:15672
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

But i cant reach the web interface from external ips

```
curl -i http://serverRemoteIp:15672
curl: (7) Failed connect to serverRemoteIp:15672; Connection timed out
```

the server is remote, so i need access from remote ips

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

First, yesterday I exec this on my server

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 15672 -j ACCEPT
```

and the problem continue. Yoday I run:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 15672 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

and works!!